# Getting a view's index in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout

So I have a LinearLayout set up in my XML file, and I dynamically add a bunch of CardViews to it through code upon startup of my activity. How can I make it so that when I click on any of the CardViews, I am able to obtain its position?

I tried setting up on an `onClickListener` for the LinearLayout, as well as an OnClickLIstener for each individual card, but couldn't find a way to obtain the index of the card that was clicked.

I'd really like to know where to put the `onClickListener`, and how to obtain the position that was clicked so that I can start a new activity based on what was clicked.

Here is my code:

```java
private LinearLayout sLinearLayout;
private CardView[] cardViews;
private Workout[] workouts;
private ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.saved_workouts);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Parcelable[] parcelableArrayExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_WORKOUTS);
    workouts = new Workout[parcelableArrayExtra.length];
    System.arraycopy(parcelableArrayExtra, 0, workouts, 0, parcelableArrayExtra.length);
    sLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.viewList);

    // Set the CardView layoutParams
    params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    populateCardViews();
    populateLayout();

}

//TODO: this method will populate the linear layout, filling the list.
private void populateLayout() {

    for (CardView cardView : cardViews) {
        sLinearLayout.addView(cardView);
    }

}

//TODO: this method will fill up the CardViews array with an array of workouts.
private void populateCardViews() {
    cardViews = new CardView[workouts.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++) {
        CardView card = new CardView(this);
        card.setClickable(true);
        card.setLayoutParams(params);
        // Set CardView corner radius
        card.setRadius(9);
        // Set cardView content padding
        card.setContentPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
        // Set a background color for CardView
        card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        // Set the CardView maximum elevation
        card.setMaxCardElevation(50);
        // Set CardView elevation
        card.setCardElevation(25);
        // Initialize a new TextView to put in CardView

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        tv.setText("Workout WorkTime: " + workouts[i].getWorkTime());
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        card.setTag(workouts[i].getWorkTime());
        card.addView(tv);

        cardViews[i] = card;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can `setOnClickListener` for each individual card. The index of clicked card is `i`

```
for (int i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++) {
    ...

    final int finalI = i;
    card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("TAG", "You click at card: " + finalI);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I not good to add so much layout programmatically. You can use a recycler view and an adapter to show a list of items. You can read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

By the way, in your case: when you create a Cardview, just add `onClickListener` to it and the index of your Cardview is the index of it in Cardview list.

```
CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //handle click here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
cardview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         int index = linearLayout.indexOfChild(v);

        }
    });
```